# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Для такой непредсказуемой погоды как в Москве или других регионах России, данная продукция является отличным вариантом.

Comment: 1. «В Москве» здесь читается как город, но Москва — часть региона Москва (слово не склоняется). 2. «Или других регионах» означает, что это все остальные регионы, но не это же имел в виду автор! «Как в регионе Москва, так и во многих других в России», — так будет чище.

Comment: А что это за "регион Москва" такой?

Comment: Регион Москва является административной единицей государства Россия. © https://geogoroda.ru/gorod/moskva-rossiya